# ng-repeat not working properly in html compile in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My html variable which I am creating in controller dynamically and adding in view through compile:

```
html ='<div class="color-label-wrapper objective-list" ng-repeat="event in events  | filter: search: strict">{{event.event}}</div>';
$scope.funnelArray = [];
$scope.funnelArray.push({funnel: $compile(html)($scope)});
```

My events array:

```
$scope.events = [{event: 'Event 1'}, {event: 'Event 2'}, {event: 'Event 3'}, {event: 'Event 4'}, {event: 'Event 5'}, {event: 'Event 6'}, {event: 'Event 7'}];
```

I need to display this array upto Event 7, but on executing its displaying Event 1 to Event 7 up to 7 times...

Please help me out..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Show us your current output and desired one

Comment: Provide a plunkr or jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

I got my desired output:

I was doing 2 times compilation due to that error occurs:

```
plunker link:
```